# Why is emacs saying my theme is undefined?

Tags: themes, customize

I'm pretty new to emacs customization and lisp, so I don't really know how to debug this problem.

I'm trying to install a custom theme. [Here's a link to the .el file.](https://github.com/TheQZ/emerald-emacs/blob/master/emerald-theme.el#L27)

The theme's load-path is set correctly, and it shows up in the `M-x customize-themes` menu, but when I try to enable it I get this in the echo area:

```
Undefined Custom theme emerald
```

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29357199/729907) help at all?

Comment: Are you adding the theme to you're load-path or you custom-theme-load-path?

Comment: Drew, I added `(package-initialize)` to my `.emacs`, but nothing changed.

Comment: Jordon, it's `custom-theme-load-path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. My fault entirely. I had been changing the name of the theme, and forgot to change some of the name definitions (e.g. `deftheme emerald`) in the theme file. Now it works fine. Thanks for your help, anyways!